# How to make a AWS Data Pipeline ShellCommandActivity Script execute a python file

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working with an AWS Data Pipeline that has a ShellCommandActivity that sets the script uri to bash file located in a s3 bucket. The bash file copies a python script located in the same s3 bucket to a EmrCluster and then the script tries to execute that python script.

[image]

This is my pipeline export:

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "name": "DefaultResource1",
      "id": "ResourceId_27dLM",
      "amiVersion": "3.9.0",
      "type": "EmrCluster",
      "region": "us-east-1"
    },
    {
      "failureAndRerunMode": "CASCADE",
      "resourceRole": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole",
      "role": "DataPipelineDefaultRole",
      "pipelineLogUri": "s3://project/bin/scripts/logs/",
      "scheduleType": "ONDEMAND",
      "name": "Default",
      "id": "Default"
    },
    {
      "stage": "true",
      "scriptUri": "s3://project/bin/scripts/RunPython.sh",
      "name": "DefaultShellCommandActivity1",
      "id": "ShellCommandActivityId_hA57k",
      "runsOn": {
        "ref": "ResourceId_27dLM"
      },
      "type": "ShellCommandActivity"
    }
  ],
  "parameters": []
}
```

This is RunPython.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
aws s3 cp s3://project/bin/scripts/Test.py ./
python ./Test.py
```

This is Test.py

```
__author__ = 'MrRobot'
import re
import os
import sys
import boto3

print "We've entered the python file"
```

From the Stdout Log I get:

> download: s3://project/bin/scripts/Test.py to ./

From the Stdeer Log I get:

> python: can't open file 'Test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I have also tried replacing python ./Test.py with python Test.py, but I get the same result.

How do I get my AWS Data Pipeline to execute my Test.py script.

*EDIT*

When I set scriptUri to s3://project/bin/scripts/Test.py I get the following errors
:

> /mnt/taskRunner/output/tmp/df-0947490M9EHH2Y32694-59ed8ca814264f5d9e65b2d52ce78a53/ShellCommandActivityIdJiZP720170209T175934Attempt1_command.sh: line 1: **author**: command not found
>   /mnt/taskRunner/output/tmp/df-0947490M9EHH2Y32694-59ed8ca814264f5d9e65b2d52ce78a53/ShellCommandActivityIdJiZP720170209T175934Attempt1_command.sh: line 2: import: command not found
>   /mnt/taskRunner/output/tmp/df-0947490M9EHH2Y32694-59ed8ca814264f5d9e65b2d52ce78a53/ShellCommandActivityIdJiZP720170209T175934Attempt1_command.sh: line 3: import: command not found
>   /mnt/taskRunner/output/tmp/df-0947490M9EHH2Y32694-59ed8ca814264f5d9e65b2d52ce78a53/ShellCommandActivityIdJiZP720170209T175934Attempt1_command.sh: line 4: import: command not found
>   /mnt/taskRunner/output/tmp/df-0947490M9EHH2Y32694-59ed8ca814264f5d9e65b2d52ce78a53/ShellCommandActivityIdJiZP720170209T175934Attempt1_command.sh: line 5: import: command not found
>   /mnt/taskRunner/output/tmp/df-0947490M9EHH2Y32694-59ed8ca814264f5d9e65b2d52ce78a53/ShellCommandActivityIdJiZP720170209T175934Attempt1_command.sh: line 7: print: command not found

**EDIT 2**

Added the following line to Test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then I received the following error:

> error: line 6, in  import boto3 ImportError: No module named boto3

using @franklinsijo 's advice I created a Bootstrap Action on the EmrCluster with the following value:

> s3://project/bin/scripts/BootstrapActions.sh

This is BootstrapActions.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo pip install boto3
```

This worked!!!!!!!

Comment: Why not reference the python script directly in `ScriptUri`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I get the following error from ref. the python script in ScriptUri: s3://project/bin/scripts/Test.py: No such file or directory. My s3 link is: https://s3.amazonaws.com/project/bin/scripts/Test.py

Comment: changed the name and got the same error.

Comment: And you are sure the file exists in the bucket with the same prefix?

Comment: I'm looking at it right now. Should I add the amazonaws.com in the ScriptUri?

Comment: No, it should be just `s3://project/bin/scripts/Test.py` if this is the file key in the bucket.

Comment: See my edit. The 'No such file or directory' error was bc I was using command instead of scriptUri.

Comment: Add `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line to your python script.

Comment: with your changes I am getting this error: line 6, in <module> import boto3 ImportError: No module named boto3    Eventually I will need boto3, I think we are a sneeze away!

Comment: Yes, boto3 module has to be installed on the Resource where this ShellCommandActivity is defined to run.

Comment: How is that done?

Comment: I have updated it as the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Configure ShellCommandActivity with

- Pass the S3 Uri Path of the python file as the `Script Uri`.
- Add the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the
  script.
- If any non-default python libraries are used in the script, install them on the target resource.

  - If `runsOn` is chosen, Add the installation commands as the [bootstrap action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html) for the EMR Resource.
  - If `workerGroup` is chosen, Install all the libraries on the [Worker group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-how-task-runner-user-managed.html) before pipeline activation.

Use either `pip` or `easy_install` to install the python modules.

Comment: That worked. I wish I could vote this up 10 more times!

Answer (score 0):

This is a helpful thread to address a simple problem that was surprisingly difficult to debug.  I ended up using the Resource's - Run As User field set to root.  I hate running as root (I tried ec2-user to no avail), but it was the only thing that gave my python script the permissions on site-packages.  Apparently the TaskRunner service doesn't have sudo access so running sudo commands inside the .sh just fails silently.