# What's the best way to run a python script daily?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a python script that connects to Redshift, executes a series of SQL commands, and generates a new derived table.

But for the life of me, I can't figure out a way to have it automatically run every day.

I've tried [AWS Data Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456182/run-a-python-script-via-aws-data-pipelines?noredirect=1&lq=1) but my shell script won't run the first copy statement.
I can't get Lambda or Glue to work because my company's IAM policies are restrictive.
Airflow seems like overkill to just run a single python script daily.

Any suggestions for services to look into?

Comment: Other than a cron job?

Comment: I have a batch job to trigger the script which I have scheduled to run automatically daily.

Comment: Apply for an IAM policy change ;-)

Comment: Lambda is made for this kind of stuff. Talk to your bosses about changing the IAM Policy. It seems silly to use the wrong tool for the job and waste AWS resources and cash on an EC2 instance for this.

Comment: I like Data Pipeline b/c we have other SQL-based derived tables built there, so it's a central spot to monitor.  Also I was following: http://themrmax.github.io/2015/08/24/A-Python-Script-on-AWS-Data-Pipeline.html
But I'll try to make progress on Lambda, it seems more broadly useful anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a cron job on an ec2 instance or set up a scheduled event to invoke your aws python lambda function http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

Answer (score 7):

Cron job?

```
00 12 * * * /home/scottie/bin/my_python_script.py
```

Run `my_python_script.py` at the top of the hour (0th minute), at noon, every day.

Comment: My limited understanding is that I'd need a server to run that on

Answer (score 1):

I use a scheduled task on Windows. Either enter it using the GUI or the [at command](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313565/how-to-use-the-at-command-to-schedule-tasks).

Comment: On a Mac.  Plus what happens if your machine is off?

Comment: I gather that the task scheduler is able to [wake from sleep](https://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/) mode. I know very little about Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AWS Glue or have some other reason to install a development endpoint, you can use Apache Zeppelin to run any code from any language (if you have the jar files) on a schedule based on a cron command. Here's the notebook I use to run Redshift nightly maintenance:

[Redshift Maintenance in a Zeppelin notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWBTh.png)